# How can I dodge missiles while playing a fighter-jet match?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am having a hard time determining the easiest way or a strategy for dodging missiles when playing the fighter jet free-for-all in GTA V Online.   I have tried stalling out, slowing down, or turning sharply while holding down the thruster... Most of the time, this fails me and I get blown out of the sky.

What tactics can I use when doing air to air combat with jets to survive longer?  Is there a way to deploy flares?

Comment: It's singleplayer only, but I believe it should apply to *GTA Online* as well: perform a looping. It's the only reliable way I've found to avoid missiles so far; both in *GTA 5* and *GTA San Andreas*.

Comment: I haven't gotten into a jet deathmatch yet, but if it's similar to other games you could also try turning on your side, pulling back on the stick, cutting the thrust and then thrusting hard to do a sharp turn.  Typically missiles aren't good with sharper turns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done this in both online and offline and have a 90-95% success rate...

As soon as you hear the missile lock alarm, you want to perform a roll-off-the-top. As soon as the alarm sounds, pull back hard on the stick at full throttle to start your loop. The moment you are at the top of your loop, roll over so your fighter is level with the ground again.

When successful, you should see the missile pass high to your left or right and you have also broken visual contact with the other combatant.

Note - If you are just leaving the military base with the jet, especially online, after completing the roll-off-the-top you want to immediately drop your altitude to as close to the ground as possible, ideally over the ocean. This will prevent the base from getting another missile lock on you.

Answer (score 7):

All of these answers are nice, but now you're talking to someone who trains pilots on GTA 5. :p

The off the top response was good, but what you will want to do, is get as much altitude as you can before hearing the lock on. The moment you hear this, you will motion your plane at a hard downwards angle; But pulling to the left or right. By this time, you will have oriented your jet to normal flying and have a clear target on your enemy.

I've watched a lot of people try the pull up to the side trick; And about 8-10 of them had been shot down by me; Here's why. 
I see them pulling up to curve, and I will instantly pull up as well and aim my actual cannons in front of them just a bit. By the time they are fully turned around like the above post, I already started firing at the nose of the plane and letting the pilot fly into the burst of explosive rounds. The earliest I've caught someone was they were in mid turn and I've caught them right in the center mass of the plane.

Comment: This is amazing advice and should be upvoted more

Answer (score 0):

When you hear wild beeping, stray left on a 45 degree angle and it should fly past you. I tried this on single player offline when I got in the military base and stole their plane. LOL

Answer (score -1):

Yeah if you keep looking behind you when stealing a jet the other jet won't spawn but I'm starting to let the jet spawn so i can practice dodging his missiles, the tactic I've been trying is just perform a barrel roll while while holding the rudder (R1 or L1) or keep on flying up and down sharply continuously about pitching up and down for about 1 to 2 seconds each and I've been successful about 50% of the time which to me isn't bad considering the military pilots jets missiles follow you like crazy and when they do miss it's like 1 inch off lol

Answer (score -3):

There's a video on YouTube that says the jets have flares.

Click and hold the left stick as you're stealing the plane, hold it down until you have to pull back to take off, and when you hear the beeping of a missile lock tap y/triangle 3 times quickly, and you will shoot off flares.

This may be a mod, though.

Comment: Please consider posting a link to this video, or better yet embed it into your post.

Comment: The Lazer does not have flares.

Comment: Sounds like you're trolling. lol

Answer (score -3):

I have found that if you push down the right stick, (to look behind you) the other plane doesn't spawn. So if you are just stealing a jet just for fun, look behind you and pull back on the throttle so you are going up from the ground at about 75 degrees and continue this for about 5-8 seconds. Then resume normal flight.